How to format a graph using vba in excel
I have a function in vba which creates a graph and formats the x axis to 'd-mmm'
I then implement the following function Update_graph() which adds the values to the graph.
Sub Update_graph()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    

    Dim row As Long
    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim increase As Double
    
    Dim chartSeries As Series
    Set chartSeries = chartObj.chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    
    
    Dim dataPoints() As Double
    Dim xValues() As Variant
    Dim dataPointCount As Long
    

    For row = 4 To 8
    
        
        currentDate = Format(ws.Cells(row, 1).Value, "d-mmm")
        increase = CalculatePercentageIncrease(ws, row) * 100
        
        ReDim Preserve dataPoints(1 To dataPointCount + 1)
        ReDim Preserve xValues(1 To dataPointCount + 1)
        dataPoints(dataPointCount + 1) = increase
        xValues(dataPointCount + 1) = currentDate
        
        dataPointCount = dataPointCount + 1
        
        
    Next row
    
    
    chartSeries.Values = dataPoints
    chartSeries.xValues = xValues
    

End Sub

The function works as expected however it changes the date format to m-dd-yy. I have tried reapplying the formatting in the update graph function however it has no effect. I have also tried changing the formatting manually in format graph settings however it also has no effect.
Graph shown here:


You should format an axis, not data. Dates should be real dates, not text.
Something like this:
Sub GenerateChart()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$B$4:$C$8")
        With .Axes(xlCategory)
            .CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
            .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "d-mmm;@"
        End With
    End With
End Sub



I’m sorry if it wasn’t clear in the question, I have tried that and initially when I create the graph the axis is formatted correctly, however once I run the update graph function it reverts the format and I can’t change it. I have tried reapplying the format after I add the data but it still has no effect.

I think, these is because you try to enter data formatted as text as your x-values. currentDate = Format(ws.Cells(row, 1).Value, "d-mmm")
They should be numbers, not text. Skip this formatting.

I changed it to currentDate = ws.Cells(row, 1).Value and it had no effect.

If x-values are dates (numbers) and tick labels are properly formatted the chart should look like in my screenshot. Did you check both?

Yes have checked both, could it be something to do with how I add the data. I had to look that code up so not entirely sure how it works/ formats the info?
